# Why does SIGTSTP exist when there is already SIGSTOP?

Tags: terminal, signals

I always thought that `Ctrl-Z` in a terminal (while in canonical mode) generates `SIGSTOP`, but according to `man 3 tcsetattr`, it generates `SIGTSTP` instead. However, in both cases, `SIGCONT` is used to resume the stopped processes.

What is the reason that `Ctrl-Z` does not just generate `SIGSTOP`? Is there a case in which it is useful for a program to handle `SIGTSTP` differently than `SIGSTOP`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like KILL, STOP can’t be caught, blocked, or ignored: it always stops the receiving process. TSTP on the other hand can be ignored or handled in a different way; for example, shells, and Emacs, set up TSTP handlers to deal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> themselves. This behaviour in shells ensures that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is always safe, and won’t get you stuck in a terminal with a stopped process and no way of resuming it.

Comment: `SIGSTOP` can be send only through command `kill -STOP pid` and `SIGTSTP` can be send in 2 ways, through command and by `ctrl` + `z` - Am I correct?

Comment: Anything that can send a signal can send any signal. As far as keyboard shortcuts go, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/343611/414739) for details of the signals that can be sent using the standard Unix-style line discipline.